# How to connect to a VPN?

Tags: kubuntu, vpn, vpnc

I am a newbie on this subject, and I was told to connect to a VPN from my computer, which is running Kubuntu 13.10. I was also given the server to connect to (vpn.server_x.com:81), a user and its password. The last data I have is that this is a openconnect on Linux.

I read several tutorials and I tried with `vpnc`, `openvpn` and `pptp-linux`, because I do not know which I have to use. I always get errors, and reading /var/log/syslog is not being very useful because I do not know if I am doing stupid things.

For example, at the beginning I supposed that I had to use `vpnc`, so I installed it and then created a new connection via the Network settings, but it asks me for Gateway, User name, User password, Group name and Group password. In gateway I wrote `vpn.server_x.com:81`, but I do not have enough data to fill in the rest.

Am I creating the right VPN connection?

Comment: take a look at this it might help you https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openvpn.html

Comment: @Creator Should I use openvpn then? (not vpnc neither pptp)?

Comment: yeah I think so because official pages are offering native and good info always

Comment: @Creator but with openvpn I need to have my public RSA key stored in the authorized_keys of the server, don't I? It would be a problem, because I do not have any access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed the solution, I did not have to install neither vpnc nor openvpn nor pptp.

I had to install openconnect. Then, the process is similar to others, add the VPN in the connection editor but selecting openconnect instead of the other ones. If I do this, I am only asked for gateway, username and password, so the data I was given is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can consult our setup guides for Linux from SumoVPN https://www.sumovpn.com/guides/ubuntu/openvpn.html